# Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch java

Tags: java, heroku, jar, discord-jda

I upload the .jar file of my bot for discord to heroku. Everything works as it should. And then the app breaks down and everything stops working.

**Application Logs**

```
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/DiscordBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -Dserver.port=43997`
app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
app[web.1]: [main] INFO net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA - Login Successful!
app[web.1]: [JDA MainWS-ReadThread] INFO net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient - Connected to WebSocket
app[web.1]: [JDA MainWS-ReadThread] INFO net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA - Finished Loading!
heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

**Procfile**

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/DiscordBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -Dserver.port=$PORT
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=${PORT:8080}
```

Answer (score 0):

worker: java -jar target/DiscordBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

**without** server.port=${PORT:8080} **in application.properties**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).